# How to add created_at and updated_at when creating a table with a Rails migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-migrations

```
Rails g migration CreateFoo
```

This does not add created_at and update_at to the migration. Is there a way to generate a migration and add timestamps as a param?

`Rails g migration CreateFoo timestamps` didn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like those only get generated automatically with models.

Otherwise you can add it manually in a `create` with `t.timestamps` or with `add_timestamps :foo` to `change` an existing table.

Answer (score 7):

You need to destroy that table and generate again

```
Rails g migration CreateFoo
```

and check the generated migration file whether `timestamp` mehtods is there or not. if not then put like this

```
t.timestamps
```

*Edit update*

You could use either syntax.

```
t.datetime :created_at
t.datetime :updated_at
```

---

```
t.timestamps is just an abstract form of writing.
```

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 2):

You can add timestamps by doing this :-

```
change_table :table_name do |t|
  t.timestamps
end
```